# Read variable from another file in same package name and same directory in golang

Tags: go

file A

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(My_str)
}
```

file B

```
package main

var My_str string
    My_str = "hi"
```

run program with this command

```
go run .
```

but this error appears:

```
undefined: My_str
```

Comment: use go mod by `go mod init modname`

Answer (score 1):

I change declare variable to this :

var My_str = "hi"

but this is'n solved and say:

undefined: My_str

Comment: Add this to your question and remove the answer as it does not solve your issue.

Comment: Please add all the details in the question.